# Twilio : Using the body of the inbound sms to reply with a unique outbound sms

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm hoping to use Twilio programmable SMS to use the body of an incoming SMS (which in most cases will be a unique number sent from a customer). Grab that number and insert it as part of an automated outbound SMS reply. Eg: Customer sends "12345678" to my Twilio ph number. Twilio then uses the body of the SMS "12345678" and adds that to the automated outbound reply SMS "&VIN="12345678"&variant"..
Any help appreciated, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using [Twilio Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14FXnUgrZ6w&list=PLqrz4nXepkz5OwmqMONVJGBBa7grym6jx&index=14&t=3s). The incoming SMS is accessible from the Widget below the Trigger widget using liquid syntax `trigger.message.Body`.

You can then use a [Send Message Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-message) to take that text from `trigger.message.Body` and append your text, something like:

```
{{trigger.message.Body}}&VIN=12345678&variant
```

in the message body of the Send Message Widget.